# Must header files be created separately now in Yosemite?

Tags: xcode, osx-yosemite

When I used to add a new objective-c file to my project, it would add the implementation and header files. Now, in Yosemite and Xcode 6.0.1, adding a new file only adds the implementation file. Is there a way to make it add both the header and implementation automatically like it used to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need Xcode 6.1 to develop for Yosemite. 6.0.x has only the 10.9 and iOS 8 SDKs—[the 10.10 SDK is in 6.1](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action).
2. Choose "Cocoa Class" in the new file sheet and you'll still get the option to create both .h and .m files together, as well as the new option to choose ObjC or Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a source for point number 1? Because I'm pretty certain my Xcode version said 6.0.1 last night.

Comment: Ok, sorry I read as "to develop in Yosemite". Now I see you mean actually development _for_ Yosemite